# Получить значение атрибута xml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Доброго времени суток!

Язык программирования *PHP*. Преобразую строку в XML объект:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
```

Вывожу на экран `echo var_dump($xml);`

Получаю такой результат:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (6) {
  ["url"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["domain"]=>
      string(13) "https://ya.ru"
    }
  }
  ["yaca"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["url"]=>
      string(13) "https://ya.ru"
    }
  }
  ["tcy"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["rang"]=>
      string(1) "6"
      ["value"]=>
      string(4) "9500"
    }
  }
  ["topics"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) {
    ["topic"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) {
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["title"]=>
        string(43) "Тема: Поисковые системы"
        ["url"]=>
        string(26) "http://yaca.yandex.ru/yca/"
      }
    }
  }
  ["textinfo"]=>
  string(113) "

Тема: Поисковые системы
Регион: Россия
Источник: Официальный"
  ["r1"]=>
  string(132) "wutwrfslmeextvlpphhotyoutxbmkulbvyuokbuxsocurtftohkircrhsjqjubpnlwfmxuhjgaxyxjrynbllcrqvtobsbtqiraide1d522c48423e52e8f6796dc9f1b3125"
}
```

Не могу сообразить, как мне получить значение `value` поля `tcy`. Обращаюсь как к массиву, но всегда пустой результат.

Добавил исходный XML:

```
<urlinfo>
<url domain="https://yandex.ru">
<![CDATA[ / ]]>
</url>
<yaca url="https://yandex.ru"/>
<tcy rang="6" value="380000"/>
<topics></topics>
<textinfo></textinfo>
<r1>
uvyerddwhdmcirwatmowxmyxpktyjugqbnhwbufhgmfvugvofkvjbfkaykbtndygknieqitmtjousnxtjjospvednwjemswehrlo68dda255ecb7540b7f383df508b14e8f
</r1>
</urlinfo>
```

Спасибо!

Comment: исходный XML бы лучше привели

Comment: @teran, добавил.

Answer (score 1):

Могу ошибиться с позицонированием, не видя xml, но значения атрибута получаются просто указанием их имени как для ассоциативного массива. Вот так

```
echo $xml->tcy['value']
```

[Подробнее об использовании Simplexml](http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Comment: Отлично! Удачи!

Answer (score 1):

```
function xmlAttribute($object, $attribute){
    if(isset($object[$attribute]))
        return (string) $object[$attribute];
    else
        return null;
}

$tcyValue=xmlAttribute($xml->tcy->attributes(),"value")
```

Если структуру не напутал. Весь смысл в том, что к св-ву объекта `@attributes` напрямую нельзя обратиться. Один раз даже получалось через переменную вроде, типа:

```
$attributes="@attributes";
echo $xml->tcy->$attributes['value'];
```

Но потом как-то не заладилось, и я стал всегда использовать вариант выше.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: @DaemonHK, вообще очень странно про *потом как-то не заладилось*. Только при наличии пространства имен могу себе такое представить